# async/ await not waiting for async.map call to be completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

In my Node.js app I'm trying to use a helper function to gather and format some data to ultimately be returned via an API endpoint. I need to loop through an array, and for each entry, make an asynchronous call to my database. However, I'm unable to return this new array of data in my route once I map over it. I believe that this has something to do with the nature of 'async.map' but have been unable to figure it out from the docs. Am I missing something? Better way to do this?

```
router.get('/route',async (req,res) => {
    const formattedData = await module.formatData(data);
    // formattedData IS RETURNED AS UNDEFINED HERE
    res.json({data:formattedData});
};
```

Relevant helper functions:

```
formatData: async(data) => {
    // gets entire object from the id that I originally had
    getNewData: (dataID) => {
        const data = Data.find({_id:dataID},(error,response)=>{
          return response;
        })
        return data;
    },
    const formatDataHelper = async(data,done) =>{
      // THIS function queries database (reason I have to use async)
      const newData = await getNewData(data);
      done(null, newData);
    }
    function dataMap(data, callback) {
      async.map(data, formatDataHelper, callback);
    }

    const returnData = await dataMap(data,(err,response)=>{
      return response;
    })

    return returnData;

},
```

Comment: `await` waits for promises. Not things that take callbacks and return nothing.

Comment: Don't use async.js in combination with promises!

Comment: Does `self.getNewData()` return a promise?  If not, we will need to see the actual database call you're trying to loop over in order to make a concrete coding suggestion.

Comment: It does.@jfriend00

Comment: @PatrickConnors It really doesn't look like it, though. If `find` was using promises, why would you have to pass a callback to it?

Comment: You're right - wasn't thinking, it returns a callback.

Answer (score 0):

`await` only awaits something when you `await` a function that returns a promise that is linked to whatever you want to `await`.  Your `dataMap()` function returns nothing, therefore `await` on that function doesn't await anything.

So, in order to work with `await`, your `dataMap()` function needs to return a promise that is tied to the asynchronous operation it is doing.

Comment: ah, totally makes sense. How would I configure the function so that the value returned by the callback is then returned to the parent function?

Comment: @PatrickConnors - Well, to use `await`, you need to convert your async operations to promises.  The code you've included doesn't actually show your actual async operations and it isn't entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish with `dataMap()` so I'm not really sure what exactly to recommend.  You'd have to describe in words what the goal is for `formatData()` and then include all supporting information about what's supposed to happen in it so that we could suggest a new implementation.

Comment: @PatrickConnors - I'm guessing you don't want to use the `async` library at all since you generally either pick the style of the async library with callbacks or you pick promises and don't mix the two.

Comment: I updated my code to make it more clear what it is I'm trying to accomplish. How using just promises would you recommend going about what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @PatrickConnors = What database are you using?  Chances are it has a built-in promise interface and you should start with that rather than the plain callback you are using now.  You can then `await` a promise coming directly from the database.

Comment: I'm using mongodb.

Comment: @PatrickConnors - I don't know mongodb myself, but I'm pretty sure it does have a promise interface so you should look in the doc for how to use that.

Answer (score -1):

use  this code to make map wait to execute your function  :

```
  you_array.map(async(elm)=>{
                 const findElement = await you_model.findById(elm?._id)
         })
```

Comment: They [are calling `map` from async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map), not the vanilla one.